# Simple configurable web server docker image for test environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a microservice that sends HTTP requests to an external non-dockerized service.

**Can anybody point me to a docker image of a simple web servicer, that I can start as part of my test environment?** Ideally, it should be simple to customize (endpoints, ports, etc) and provide some meaningful logging of the incoming requests.

Comment: It's hard to tell what exactly your requirements are. The most simplistic one should be [scratch](https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch/) though.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at my project: https://github.com/mateuszgruszczynski/cinema its very crude and simple setup I use for performance test trainings. It contains few containers:

- cinema-http / cinema-gateway - scala/akka based microservices
- frontend - apache http server + simple php/js webpage
- haproxy - haproxy as loadbalancer
- plus some extra containers: postgres, mysql, jenkins, graphite, grafana

When it comes to dockerfiles and composer file it strongly depends on what technology you want to use for http server.

It does not have any extra logging but it should be easy to add, or maybe standard apache http logs will be enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your preference for vendor. Here are some to choose from:

- Linux:

  - [Nginx](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/)
  - [Apache httpd](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/)
- Microsoft:

  - [IIS](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/iis/)

The links to those pages show you a few different distro's for each and contain the configuration information.